# How do I dump the contents of an ELF file at a specific address?

Tags: gdb, elf, objdump, readelf

Using GDB, if I load an ELF image and give it an address, I can get GDB to dump the contents of the ELF file at that address.  For example:

```
p *((MYSTRUCT *)0x06f8f5b0)
$1 = {
  filename = 0x6f8f5e0 <bla> "this is a string", format = 0x6f8f640 <pvt> "This is another string!\n", lineNumber = 148, argumentCount = 0 '\000', printLevel = 1 '\001'}
```

This works because GDB has loaded the ELF image and parsed its relocation tables, and it's also aware of the layout of MYSTRUCT.

How do I do the same thing without GDB?  I actually don't really care about parsing MYSTRUCT.  I just want a dump of 20 bytes at location 0x06f8f5b0.  I've tried playing with readelf and objdump, but I couldn't get what I wanted.

Python code (e.g. using pyelftools) would also be acceptable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I just want a dump of 20 bytes at location 0x06f8f5b0.

Your question only makes sense in the context of position-dependent (i.e. `ET_EXEC`) binary (any other binary can be loaded at arbitrary address).

For a position-dependent binary, the answer is pretty easy:

- iterate over program headers until you find one which "covers" desired address,
- from `.p_vaddr` and `.p_offset` compute the offset in the file
- use `lseek` and `read` to read the bytes of interest.

To make this more concrete, here is an example:

```
// main.c
const char foo[] = "This is the song that never ends.";
int main() { printf("&foo = %p\n", &foo[0]); return 0; }

gcc -w -no-pie main.c

./a.out ; ./a.out
&foo = 0x402020
&foo = 0x402020

readelf -Wl a.out | grep LOAD

  Type           Offset   VirtAddr           PhysAddr           FileSiz  MemSiz   Flg Align
  LOAD           0x000000 0x0000000000400000 0x0000000000400000 0x000438 0x000438 R   0x1000
  LOAD           0x001000 0x0000000000401000 0x0000000000401000 0x0001bd 0x0001bd R E 0x1000
  LOAD           0x002000 0x0000000000402000 0x0000000000402000 0x000190 0x000190 R   0x1000
  LOAD           0x002e10 0x0000000000403e10 0x0000000000403e10 0x000220 0x000228 RW  0x1000
```

Here we see that the address we care about is 0x20 bytes into the 3rd `LOAD` segment, which starts at offset `0x002000` into the file.

Therefore the bytes we are interested in are at offset `0x2020` into the file.

Let's check:

```
dd if=a.out bs=1 count=15 skip=$((0x002020)) 2>/dev/null
This is the son
```

QED.